# Differences between induced vector fields on a smooth manifold and on a principal bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, fibre-bundles, principal-bundles

In the context of the connections on fibre bundle, I have found some difficulties trying to understand the fundamental vector field (my reference is Nakahara, but I'm having some problems with the chapters about fibre bundles, can someone suggest another book about this topic?).

It seems to me that the fundamental vector field is nothing more that an induced vector field, but induced by a right action instead of a left action of a Lie group on a manifold.

- Let $M$ and $G$ be a smooth manifold and a Lie group respectively and suppose to have a left action of the group on the manifold $$
  \sigma_L:(p,g)\in M\times G\rightarrow \sigma_L(p,g)\equiv gp =q \in M
  $$
  but, since $G$ is a Lie group, we can use the exponential map and write every element of the Lie group as $g=\operatorname{exp}(tV)$, where $V\in T_eG$ is a generator of the group. So we can go from a flux on the group (the set of all the integral curves of the left invariant vector field associated to $V$) to a flux on the manifold, that we can see as the set of all the integral curves of a vector field on the manifold, called induced vector field $V^\#$
  $$
  V^\#(p)=\left. \frac{d}{dt}(\operatorname{exp}(tV)p)\right|_{t=0}
  $$
  It's also possible to prove that there is an *anti*-homomorphism between $T_eG \cong\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{X}(M)$. We can define another vector field on the manifold, the fundamental vector field, using $-t$ instead of $t$ in the previous definition and in this case we have an homomorphism instead of an anti-homomorphism.
- Let $(P,\pi, M, G)$ be a principal bundle and, as such, there is a global right action of the structure group $G$ on the total space $P$. Since $P$ is a manifold and $G$ is a Lie group acting on $P$, we can follow the previous steps in order to define a fundamental vector field on the principal bundle (since the action is a right action, we have the fundamental vector field directly, with the plus sign in the definition). So we know that, evaluating a fundamental vector field in a point $u\in P$
  $$
  V^\#(u)=\left. \frac{d}{dt}(u \operatorname{exp}(tV))\right|_{t=0} \in T_uP
  $$
  but we also know that $\pi(u)=\pi(ug)=p\in M\ \ \forall g \in G$,therefore the integral curve of the fundamental field with initial point $u\in P$ is a curve contained entirely in the fiber $G_{\pi(u)}$ so we can conclude that every vector $V^\#(u)$ is a vector tangent to the principal bundle in the point $u$ which is also tangent to the fiber in that point.

At this point I have some problems with some statements:

1. *There is an homomorphism between $T_eG \cong\mathfrak{g}$ and $V_uP$.* Why the homomorphism is with $V_uP$ instead of the set of all the fundamental vector fields (like the "general" case, where the homomorphism is with $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ and not with $T_pM$)?
2. Then, when the horizontal subspace is defined, Nakahara says that $T_uP=V_uP\oplus H_uP$ and states "*a smooth vector field $X$ on $P$ is separated into smooth vector fields $X^V\in V_uP$ and $X^H\in H_uP$ as $X=X^V+X^H$*". Therefore $V_uP$ is the set of all the fundamental vector fields? I had understood that it was the set of all the vertical vectors in $u\in P$, that you can get evaluating all the fundamental vector fields in the same point $u$, but from this statement it seems that an element of $V_uP$ is a vector field and not a vector.

Is there any difference between a fundamental vector field on a manifold and a fundamental vector field on a principal bundle?

---

EDIT (1): this edit is inspired by Dmitri Pavlov's comment

Since the fiber $G$ (which is the structure Lie group in the case of a principal bundle) is diffeomorphic to the fiber in each point $G_p$, where $p\in M$, I expect that there is an isomorphism between the "tangent space" of $G$ (its Lie algebra) and the "tangent space" of $G_p$ (which I suppose is the set of all the $V_uP$ for each $u$ such that $\pi_P(u)=p$ [$\pi_P:P\rightarrow M$], or $\pi_{VP}^{-1}(G_p)$ equivalently [$\pi_{VP}:VP\rightarrow P$]). Is the set of all the $V_uP$ for each $u$ such that $\pi_P(u)=p$ also the set of all the fundamental vector fields of the fiber $G_P$? If so, this isomophism would be what I expect from the "general" case (isomorphism between the algebra and the set of fundamental vector fields on $P$)? Why here we use the vertical space only in one point $u$ of the fiber and we don't consider the other points? Even if all this reasoning is wrong (and probably it is since I'm not well versed in this topic), I was wondering if therefore there are TWO isomorphisms, one between the algebra and $V_uP$ (as a consequence of the isomorphism between $G$ and the fiber in each point, like Dmitri Pavlov said - but like I explained in this edit, I don't understand this explanation fully) and another between the algebra and the set of all the fundamental vector fields (as a consequence of the definition of fundamental vector field, like in the "general" case).

---

EDIT (2): I found another book (Topics in Physical Mathematics by K. Marathe) where the author says

"*A vector field $Y\in \mathfrak{X}(P)$ is said to be a vertical vector field if $Y(u)$ is tangent to the fiber of $P$ through $u$, $\forall u \in P$. We denote by $\mathfrak{V}(P)$ the set of vertical vector fields on $P$. The set $\mathfrak{V}(P)$ is called the vertical bundle
of $P$. It is a Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{X}(P)$. Since $G$ preserves the fibers (i.e., acts vertically on $P$), $\tilde{A}$ is a vertical vector field and the map
$$
\tilde{\rho}: \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{V}(P)
$$
defined by $A\rightarrow \tilde{A}$ is a Lie algebra isomorphism into $\mathfrak{V}(P)$ and induces a trivialization of the
vertical bundle $\mathfrak{V}(P) \cong P\times \mathfrak{g}$. The inverse of this isomorphism associates to a vertical vector field an element of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$.*"

It seems that there is in fact an isomorphism between the Lie algebra of the group $\mathfrak{g}$ and the set of all the vertical vector fields on $P$ (= fundamental vector fields on $P$), which would be in accordance with what I would expect based on the results of the "general" case (Lie algebra $\cong$ set of vector fields).

In any case I don't put this as an answer because it's just another source writing a different thing and I wouldn't do cherry picking, so I'd still like to have some answers about it.

Comment: Concerning Question 1: this isomorphism has nothing to do (a priori) with fundamental vector fields.  It is simply a reflection of the fact that each fiber of a principal G-bundle is (noncanonically) diffeomorphic to G.  A posteriori, the fundamental vector field for a principal bundle is a section of the vector bundle VP.  Concerning Question 2: V_u P is not a set of vector fields, it is the fiber of the vector bundle VP over a point u∈P.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I edited the post.

Comment: You can't write every element of a Lie group as an exponential of an element of the Lie algebra. But you can do so for elements in a neighborhood of the origin, and uniquely for elements of the Lie algebra near the origin.

Comment: @BenMcKay I'm sorry, is $g\operatorname{exp}(tV)$ the flow of the left-invariant vector field $X$ such that $X|_e=V\in T_eG$, where $t$ is the curve parameter and $g\in G$ the initial point? Since a left-invariant vector field is globally defined on the group, isn't its flow passing through each point of the group? I apologize in advance if I'm saying something wrong.

Comment: @Nabla: what Ben McKay is saying is that for fixed $g$, varying $t$ and $V$ in the exponential map will not surject onto all elements of the Lie group.

Comment: For example, see https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/two-small-facts-about-lie-groups/ ($SL_2(\mathbf{R})$ has points that cannot be reached by exponential map from the identity)

Comment: A simple example: the group of real 2x2 matrices of determinant 1 has Lie algebra consisting of the traceless 2x2 matrices. You can check, by real Jordan normal form, that their exponentials don't strike the negative of the identity matrix.

Comment: @WillieWong I reread what I wrote in the post, I said that we can write _every_ element of the group as $g=\operatorname{exp}(tV)$ (varying $t$ and $V$ implied), but I should have written that we can write _some_ elements of the group [...]. Therefore, is the definition of the vector fields induced by the action of the group on the manifold relative only to the elements of the group that I can write as the exponential map? While is what I said about the flow of the left-invariant vector fields correct?